# How to set ViewPort and ViewBox on a VisualBrush to create a dotted background in a WPF Canvas?

Tags: wpf, canvas, background

I want to create a `Canvas` with a snap grid. I implemented the logic to snap my objects to a 20 pixel grid in the view model, now I'm working on the view. I want the grid to look like this:

[image]

I came up with this solution, however I don't like it, seems to be a bit of a hack (it uses 4 objects for the pattern instead of 1, does this affect performance?).

```xml
<Canvas.Background>
    <VisualBrush TileMode="Tile" Viewport="0,0,20,20" ViewportUnits="Absolute" Viewbox="0,0,20,20" ViewboxUnits="Absolute">
        <VisualBrush.Visual>
            <Grid Width="20" Height="20">
                <Ellipse Height="2" Width="2" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="-1,-1"/>
                <Ellipse Height="2" Width="2" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="-1,-1"/>
                <Ellipse Height="2" Width="2" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="-1,-1"/>
                <Ellipse Height="2" Width="2" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="-1,-1"/>
            </Grid>
        </VisualBrush.Visual>
    </VisualBrush>
</Canvas.Background>
```

---

The problem is, if I use only one `Ellipse`, without the negative margin like this:

```xml
<Canvas.Background>
    <VisualBrush TileMode="Tile" Viewport="0,0,20,20" ViewportUnits="Absolute" Viewbox="0,0,20,20" ViewboxUnits="Absolute">
        <VisualBrush.Visual>
            <Grid Width="20" Height="20">
                <Ellipse Height="2" Width="2" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
            </Grid>
        </VisualBrush.Visual>
    </VisualBrush>
</Canvas.Background>
```

The ellipse center point is at 1px offset:

[image]

---

And if I add the -1px offset:

```xml
<Canvas.Background>
    <VisualBrush TileMode="Tile" Viewport="0,0,20,20" ViewportUnits="Absolute" Viewbox="0,0,20,20" ViewboxUnits="Absolute">
        <VisualBrush.Visual>
            <Grid Width="20" Height="20">
                <Ellipse Height="2" Width="2" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="-1,-1" />
            </Grid>
        </VisualBrush.Visual>
    </VisualBrush>
</Canvas.Background>
```

3/4 of the point is outside of the background tile:

[image]

---

I guess I could put the dot in the middle of the grid, but then I would have to change my view model calculation and add an offset - I consider it a bigger "hack" than the first view.

I suspect, that there should be some workaround using the `ViewPort` and `ViewBox`, but I don't quite understand them yet.

Please give me the simplest possible solution for setting my background to a dot snap grid, that has dots in a 20px grid, no offset. (E.g. dot centers on (0,0) (0,20) (20,0) (20,20) etc.)

---

**Edit:** this should be enough to reproduce the rectangle and the control:

```xml
<Canvas>
    <Canvas.Background>
        <VisualBrush TileMode="Tile" Viewport="0,0,20,20" ViewportUnits="Absolute" Viewbox="0,0,20,20" ViewboxUnits="Absolute">
            <VisualBrush.Visual>
                <Grid Width="20" Height="20">
                    <Ellipse Height="2" Width="2" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="-1,-1" />
                    <Ellipse Height="2" Width="2" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="-1,-1"/>
                    <Ellipse Height="2" Width="2" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="-1,-1"/>
                    <Ellipse Height="2" Width="2" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="-1,-1"/>
                </Grid>
            </VisualBrush.Visual>
        </VisualBrush>
    </Canvas.Background>
    <Canvas.Children>
        <Rectangle Canvas.Left="40" Canvas.Top="40" Width="100" Height="80" Fill="Yellow" Stroke="blue" />
    </Canvas.Children>
</Canvas>
```

Comment: Can you please add the Border in your sample XAML so we can get the same result?

Comment: I'll try to, but it's not easy. I add it dynamically.

Comment: Yeah I guess but please add a hardcoded one so we can test. I assume it would be something like `<Border Width="40" Height="20" Background="Yellow" />` but I'm not too sure about your offsets.

Comment: I added a sample code to the end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set both your `Viewport` and your `Viewbox` to `-1 -1 20 20"`. It will show like this:

[image: snapshot]

The `ViewBox` indicates which part of the `VisualBrush` you wish to pickup, so you have to start at `-1 -1` or you won't get the upper-left part of the circle because of your negative `Margin`.

The `ViewPort` indicates the position of the first tile in the `Canvas` background. Again, you want it at `-1 -1` to align the center of the circle on the origin of the `Canvas`.

Answer (score 1):

For a simple drawing, better use a DrawingBrush instead of a VisualBrush:

```
<DrawingBrush TileMode="Tile"
              Viewport="-10,-10,20,20" ViewportUnits="Absolute"
              Viewbox="-10,-10,20,20" ViewboxUnits="Absolute">
    <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
        <GeometryDrawing Brush="Black">
            <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                <EllipseGeometry RadiusX="1" RadiusY="1"/>
            </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
        </GeometryDrawing>
    </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
</DrawingBrush>
```

Comment: I don't know much about it, why is it better?

Comment: Because a Drawing is more lightweight than a Shape (e.g. an Ellipse). You would use a VisualBrush for more complex things that really need Visuals.